# Detecting file size in applescript

Tags: file, applescript

So I'm trying to alert myself if a certain file ever gets to big, but I didn't really find anything related to filesize on the internet. I know you could theoretically use a shell `find` command or something similar, but I don't really like using shell in combination with applescript.

```c
set theSize to the size of "/Directory/to/my/File"
if theSize > 100000 then
    display notification "This file is really big, you should delete it."
end if
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask the Finder, info for command (deprecated), AsObjC's FileManager for the size of some file:

```
tell application "Finder" to set theSize to size of ("/Directory/to/my/File" as POSIX file as alias)
-- set theSize to size of (info for "/Directory/to/my/File")

if theSize > 100000 then
    display notification "This file is really big, you should delete it."
end if
```

Comment: What does the 100000 in the code stand for? It's not bytes, I checked

Comment: Why do you think it's not bytes? System Events (and others) return size in the bytes.

Comment: I use it on a really big file (200GB) and I pressed `show info` in the rightclick menu. I copied the exact Byte Size the file had and pasted it into my script and then lowered some numbers. If I let it compile or run, it will change the number from `200422911517` to `2.00422911517E+11` and won't return true.

Comment: Integers have limits in applescript (well, pretty much any language) and when you generate one that's 2^29+ (just over 536M), it will be converted to a real number with that notation. Look up Class Reference > Integer in the Language Guide for Apple's explanation. Real numbers can be much larger.

Comment: @gurkensaas. Incredible, but it looks like you're right.
I tested with two files - 2.07 GB and 2.59 GB.
In the first case, Finder, System Events and Info For gave the correct result. In the second case, Finder and Info For again gave the correct result, and System Events converted the size to a negative number. So it's simply better to ditch System Events altogether. I will update my first suggestion to more correct.

Comment: You could let the Finder provide the size (as per the updated answer). You could probably also break it into two commands. For some reason, getting a single property sometimes generates odd results but if you get all the properties and then ask for one of them, it works. (On Sierra with a 3GB file) I get the correct results using `set xy to info for _file_` and then `size of xy`.

Comment: Incidentally, that the notation changed to exponent shouldn't be an issue. Applescript can work with numbers below 2^1024 (~308 digits) and there is no difference between the two numbers you provided above. It's more that there may be a bug in System Event's handling of large files. The breaking point seems to be just below 2.15GB (or 2^31). I guess that was a file size constraint back in the day (e.g. 32-bit computing era). You could probably test it with a big text file and then add another character and try again.